# Adding position: fixed; ruins header

Tags: html, css, css-position

Here's the code:

```css
div {
    border-radius: 5px;
    border: 1px solid green;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -ms-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
#header {
    height: 52px;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #B2D490;
    z-index: 1;

}
h1 {
    color: #FFFFFF;
    padding-left: 25px;
    margin: 0;
    display: inline;
    font-size: 27px;
    line-height: 50px;
}
h2, h3, h4, h5, h6 {
    padding-left: 10px;
    margin: 10px 0 10px 0px;
}
.left {
    height: 100%;
    width: 250px;
    background-color: #DBFFED;
    float: left;
    margin-top: 10px;
}
.right {
    height: 100%;
    width: 300px;
    background-color: #DBFFE0;
    float: right;
    margin-top: 10px;
}
#footer {
    height: 35px;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #57C449;
    clear: both;
    position: relative;
    margin-top: 10px;
}
#footer p {
    color: #FFFFFF;
    text-align: center;
    margin: auto;
    line-height: 35px;
}
span {
    color: #E3E3E3;
}
```

```html
<html>
 <head>
  <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheet.css"/>
  <title>My Title</title>
 </head>
 <body>
 <div id="header">
     <h1>My <span>Resume</span></h1>
 </div>
 <div class="left">
     <h2>Experience</h2>
         <ul>
             <p>Microsoft Certified Solutions Expert (MCSE)</p>
             <p>Expert on jQuery</p>
         </ul>
     <h3>Skills</h3>
         <ul>
                <li><p>Complex Problem Solving</p></li>
             <li><p>Flexibility</p></li>
             <li><p>Strong Work Ethic</p></li>
         </ul>
 </div>
 <div class="right">
     <h4>Education</h4>
         <ul>
             <p>Some Courses</p>
        </ul>
     <h5>Business</h5>
         <ul>
             <li><p>Cafe</p></li>
         </ul>
     <h6>Earnings</h6>
         <ul>
             <li><p>10.000/Month</p></li>
         </ul>
 </div>
 <div style="clear:both; border:none; border-radius: none;"></div>
 <div id="footer">
     <p>© 2015 Some Text</p>
 </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

or http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ojXpxx

Adding position: fixed; to #header ruins it. The header gets lower and takes some extra space to the right. 
I've spent a lot of time trying to fix this. Tried to add wrapper, change elements position etc.
Nothing seems to work. So what is the problem?
Thank You.

Comment: To answer "Whats the problem" it helps to know "What's the expectation."

Comment: Use google search with "sticky header"

Comment: Dont really know what you are trying to achieve. If you make the header fixed top it goes in front of the left and right divs, as expected. Are you sure that you really want to fix it? seems a bit weird to me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you apply position: fixed; the element will be position with respect to the view.

Try this out.

```
body{
  padding-top: 50px
}

#header {
    height: 52px;
    width: calc(100vw - 30px);
    background-color: #B2D490;
    z-index: 1;
    position: fixed;
    top: 5px;
}
```

Comment: Please avoid l33t speek and chatty acronyms in your answers.

Answer (score 0):

What I see here, is that you have some default unwanted CSS styles applied to your project. To deal with this, you need to 'reset' these styles. I would suggest adding this CSS file to your project. It will fix your problem.

[Eric Meyer's CSS Reset](http://cssreset.com/)